How to produce a "flashing" UI element in Maui
I have a working solution in WinForms and Xamarin which I am now trying to re-implement in Maui. I'm trying to make a UI element "flash" by changing color from black to red and back again, repeating.
The issue is that the code appears to function, but the UI does not change - the "flashing" UI element just sits there unchanging.
I want to "flash" the UI element at different rates - as you can see here (times are in milliseconds):
    switch (flashRate)
    {
        case FlashRate.Flashing:
            lighton.Interval = 200;
            heartbeat.Interval = 1200;
            break;
        case FlashRate.LongFlash:
            lighton.Interval = 2000;
            heartbeat.Interval = 4200;
            break;
        case FlashRate.Quick:
            lighton.Interval = 200;
            heartbeat.Interval = 975;
            break;
        case FlashRate.VeryQuick:
            lighton.Interval = 200;
            heartbeat.Interval = 562;
            break;
        case FlashRate.UltraQuick:
            lighton.Interval = 200;
            heartbeat.Interval = 370;
            break;
    }

The approach I have used so far is to use two timers:

"heat-beat" which repeats/loops.
"Light On" which tells the light when to switch off, does not repeat.

Whenever the heat-beat event fires, the UI element's color is set to Red, and the Light-On timer activated.
Whenever the Light-On event fires, the UI element's color is set to black.
private void Lighton_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    brdLightsim.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
}

private void heartbeat_Elapsed(object? sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    brdLightsim.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0);
    lighton.Start();
}

The border is defined thus:
    <Border
        x:Name="brdLightsim"
        Stroke="Gray"
        StrokeThickness="3"
        StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
        Padding="30"
        HorizontalOptions="Center">

        <Label x:Name="lblLight" Text="[Light]"
          TextColor="White"
          FontSize="18"
          Margin="20"
          FontAttributes="Bold" />
        
    </Border>

The two timer events are definitely firing (breakpoints are hit).
I can use brdLightsim.BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue; to set the color successfully on a button click (that also starts the heat-beat, etc).

have you tried using Animations?

Image supports animated GIF playback controlled by the IsAnimationPlaying property.

No, have not thought about animations - will look into that.  Thanks!

Interestingly, my code works fine on Android, its only Windows that has an issue.  Yet to investigate animations.

Could it be an issue with threads?
The button works because it's all on UI thread. I assume the flashing happens using some sort of timer on a background thread. UI work needs to be done on an UI thread like so:
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        brdLightsim.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 0);
    });


This resolved the issue when running on Windows.
